# Multiple Events on change

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, blazor-webassembly

```
<div class="name-select">
    <select class="form-select" @onchange="SelectContentName">
            @foreach (var name in Names)
            {
                <option value=@name>@name</option>
            }
        </select>
 </div>


<ul class="form">
    <li>
        <select class="form-select" @onchange="SelectContentPeriod">
            @foreach (var period in Periods)
            {
                <option value=@period>@period</option>
            }
            </select>
    </li>
    <li>
        <select class="form-select" @onchange="SelectContentYear">
            @foreach (var year in Years)
            {
                <option value=@year>@year</option>
            }
        </select>

    </li>
    <li class="list-year">
               <p class="label-period">חיפוש לפי תאריך</p>
        <select class="form-select" @onchange="SelectContentPeriod">
            @for(var i = 1; i<13 ; i++ )
            {
                <option value=@i>@i</option>
            }
        </select>
   
    </li>


</ul>
```

The methods:

```
   protected void SelectContentName(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        SelectedName = e.Value.ToString();
        data.Name = SelectedName;
    }


    protected void SelectContentYear(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {


        SelectedYear = Convert.ToInt32(e.Value);
        data.Year = SelectedYear;

      
    }


    protected void SelectContentMonth(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        SelectedMonth = Convert.ToInt32(e.Value);
        data.Month = SelectedMonth;
            
    }



    protected void SelectContentPeriod(ChangeEventArgs e )
    {
        String SelectedPeriod = e.Value.ToString();    
        data.Period = SelectedPeriod;
        
   
    }
```

My goal is to handle all event in one .if one of these events will happen , the all events will execute from this operation. I tried to to some but doesnt works yet
what I tried Is...

```
 protected void ChangeContentData(ChangeEventArgs mainEvent)
    {
        SelectContentName(bindName);
        SelectContentMonth(bindMonth);
        SelectContentPeriod(bindPeriod);
        SelectContentYear(bindYear);
       
    }
```

then I bind it to the divs................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Why do you want this?  If a field doesn't change, why do you want to waste time recomputing it?

Comment: I want to bind the actual state of the selections to object. every time that one of events executed.

Comment: Sure, but if the field that changed was the month, why waste time on the day and the year?